# How to extract 4 letters from file names and use in substitution in multiple files

Tags: perl, substr

```
my $v3test;
my $rootDir = "C:\\";
$v3test = "$rootDir"."test\\";
```

directory

```
chdir $v3test;
opendir(V3, $v3test);
my @str0 = readdir V3;
my $str0 = @str0;

local $^I = ''; 
local @ARGV = glob "*.rnx";
```

File Name: `GANS???????????????.rnx`,
`YONS???????????????.rnx`,
`GUMC???????????????.rnx`

```
my $str5 = "CREF0001";
my $str6 = substr(@ARGV[0], 0, 4);
**#I want to extract 4 words form file title**

while (<>) {

  s/\Q$str5/$str6/g;
  print;
}
```

The `*.rnx` data is GPS data.

I want to extract 4 words from `*.rnx` file title.
How can I do this?

---

*Edit:* It has been confirmed in comments that it is four *letters*, not words. Those should be used, with four spaces appended, to replace the string `$str5` in all files.

Comment: (1) "_from file title_" -- do you mean from the file _name_?   (2) "_extract 4 words_"  -- your code tries to get the first four letters from the name of the first file on the command line; do you want 4 words or 4 letters?  From each file or from one file? (3) That what you extract is used to replace things on some lines in all files -- is that what you want?

Comment: (1) "from file title" : yes, it is
(2) 4letters!!!!! 
(3) str6 = 'extract 4 letters'+4space   I want to replace the word(str5 >>>> str6)
      I want to do this all *.rnx data.

My english isn't very good.

please understand.

Comment: OK, thank you.  So you want to replace `CREF0001` by `CREF    `, everywhere in all files given on command-line.  But the question is about the file title -- what does `CREF...` have to do with file titles?  (They were `GANS....rnx`, `YONS....rnx` and `GUMC....rnx`, right?)

Comment: No ㅜㅜ I want to replace 'CREF0001' >>> 'GANS....'  (....=4spacebar)

Comment: Ah, right.  But in files with name `YONS...rnx` do you want to replace `CREF0001` with `YONS    ` ?  And the same for `GUMC...` files?

Comment: YONS, GUMC, SONP, GANS are GPS center name and *.rnx is gps data.
The *.rnx file have wrong data. So I want to fix the wrong data(CREF0001>>>GPS Center Name). Please don't rename file name. Just extract filename and paste file text.

Answer (score 3):

The following replaces `CREF0001` by a string derived from the name of the file.

So in files `YONS...rng` the string `CREF0001` is replaced by `YONS`     (four spaces), while in all files with the name `GANS...rng` the replacement is `GANS`    , etc.

With `$^I` set the files are edited in place.  I assign `~` to it so to keep a backup, `filename~`. Assign an empty string `''` instead if backup is unneeded but only once this has been well tested.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

# Assigning other than '' (empty string) keeps a backup
local $^I = '~';
local @ARGV = glob "*.rnx";

my $bad_data = 'CREF0001';

my $filename = $ARGV[0];  # initialize

# Replace $bad_data with this string
my $gps_name_string = substr($filename, 0, 4) . ' 'x4;

while (<>) { 
    if ($filename ne $ARGV) {  # a new file
        $filename = $ARGV;
        $gps_name_string = substr($filename, 0, 4) . ' 'x4;
    }

    s/$bad_data/$gps_name_string/g;

    print;
}
```

This uses the [`$ARGV` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$ARGV), which has the name of the currently processed file, to detect when the loop started processing lines from the next file, so to build the suitable replacement string.

---

I presume that there is a reason for using `local`-ized `@ARGV`, and that is fine.  I'd like to mention a couple of other options though

- Submit the glob on the command line, as `progname *.rng`, and this way `@ARGV` gets set and then `while (<>) { }` in the program processes lines from those files
- Build the file list as you do, using `glob`, but then process files by names, not using `<>`

  ```
  use warnings;
  use strict;
  use Path::Tiny;  # for path()->edit_lines

  my $bad_data = 'CREF0001';

  my @files = glob "*.rng";

  foreach my $file (@files) { 
      my $gps_name_string = substr($file, 0, 4) . ' 'x4;
      path($file)->edit_lines( sub { s/$bad_data/$gps_name_string/g } );
  }
  ```

  The `edit_lines` applies the anonymous sub in its argument, here with just the regex, to each line and rewrites the file. See [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).  Or one can open the files normally and iterate over lines as in the main text (except that now we know the filename).

Comment: 진짜 너무 감사합니다!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Yeom You are most welcome :)  (I don't speak Korean unfortunately but I looked it up)